# Hierarchical tree navigation in Django

Tags: django, navigation

I am looking for the best way to implement a tree navigation system in my Django app. I have a hierarchy of pages, and I need a way to set links as active on the various levels of the hierarchy. The only solutions that I have come across use the database in a CMS-like fashion, but that is not what I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: what criteria do you use to define what "the best" is?

Comment: Most elegant and/or easy to implement...

Answer (score 0):

django-mptt is a pretty decent implementation of the parent/child relationships with very good speed.

https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt